# how to get from a fragment to an activity without disturbing fragment's reausability

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

This is now bugging me a lot.

I want to get to an activity from a Fragment without disturbing the reusability of the fragment. That mean I cant directly start an Intent from within the fragment to a the activity the fragment is currently attached to.

Here is the code under question

```
//This is the code inside the fragment 

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();

    switch (position){
        //case 1 is the case when the user clicks the ADD List Item from a ListFragment. 
        //Position is the position of ADD in the List Fragment.
        case 1:{
            Intent intent = new Intent(/*what exactly should I put here?*/  ,  
        /*this is where the reference to activity the fragment is attached to goes.
            But we dont know what activty the fragment is attached to, as it is reusable 
         and may get attached to different activity at different times*/);
        }

        case 2:{
            //this is the case when user decides to view the entered text in the array list.
            TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            int size = workout.arrayList.size();
            Object[] array = workout.arrayList.toArray();
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                textView.setText((String)array[i] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I feels like the data may be insufficient, although I am not sure what else to provide, sorry about that.

If more data is required, tell me.

Comment: what do you exactly want ?? what do you mean by disturbing reusability..

Comment: Fragments are known for their reusability, in order to do that no fragment and activity should directly communicate with each other. You  communicate through an interface. As fragments may be used with other activities, this is essential

Comment: still dint get what you want to achieve ??

Comment: A way to get to an activity which fragment is attached to.

Comment: what do you mean by get to an activity ?? open the parent activity ?? from the fragment itself ??

Comment: Yes, opening the  activity the fragment is attached from fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165998/discussion-between-aditya-rawat-and-santanu-sur).

Answer (score 1):

Inside a Fragment we get the Context for an Intent using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AnyActivity.class);
```

OR

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getView.getContext(),AnyActivity.class);
```

The `AnyActivity()` can be any activity including the one currently having the `Fragment`.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thought that had crossed my mind. But the problem in doing this is that the fragment will pass the intent to `AnyIntent`. What if the same fragment is used in a different activity that whose name can certainly not be `AnyActivity`. In this case we need to get what activity `fragment` is current attached to.

Comment: So do you mean this `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),getActivity().getClass());` tell me if you mean this so that I can update my answer.

Comment: I don't actually know. But anyways, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the same activity like this..

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SameActivity.class);

      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

**UPDATE** To reuse the fragment for different values pass arguments to the fragment...during transaction..

```
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.put("className", "SameActivity");
      fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

in fragment get the class name from bundle ... different class will pass different arguments as bundle..

In  **OtherActivity** bundle would look like this..

```
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.put("className", "OtherActivity");
      fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: please refer to the reply I gave to Xenolion.

Comment: you are getting the current activity in which the fragment is attached by using `getActivity()` this is the reference of the current activity.. now whats the issue ?? @adityarawat

Comment: The issue is the intent is being send to `SameActivity.class`. The fragment can be reused by different activity (ex. `SomeOtherActivity`). But when the fragment's code will run it will always send the Intent to `SameActivity`,but the intent should be sent to `SomeOtherActivity` .

Comment: i have updated please ask if you have trouble understanding.. @adityarawat